# Access VBA: Method pastespecial of worksheet class failed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a **VBA** code that is supposed to export the filtered query data to Excel. When I activate the code trough an OnClick button, I get the error: 
`Method pastespecial of worksheet class failed`.

I am running **Access 2013** on a **Windows Server 2012 r2** machine.

**The VBA code:**

```
Private Sub cbExport_Click()

    On Error GoTo Command13_Click_Err

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

    Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With xlapp
        .Workbooks.Add
        .ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", _
                                  Link:=False, _
                                  DisplayAsIcon:= False

        .Cells.Select
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Visible = True
        .Range("A1").Select

    End With

    Command13_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

    Command13_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command13_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

**Picture of the UI:**
[image]

Somebody got an idea?

Comment: Sorry, can't see the image - "This site can’t be reached".  Your `.Cells.` and `.Range` are referencing the Excel application rather than a worksheet so they'll cause an error.  Not sure about the PasteSpecial - I'm used to seeing it in this format: `Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

Comment: I think it's the format bit, also a range where to put it maybe, I've tried with `ActiveSheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` and fine, are why not use CopyFromRecordset instead?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things wrong:

- You appear to have used early binding to dimension the `xlApp` variable, but then use late binding to initialize that variable.
- The [`.PasteSpecial()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) method should be used on a range object, not a sheet object.
- You appear to be using the wrong arguments on the `.PasteSpecial` method.
- The paste method should be a numeric value, part of the [`xlPasteType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx) enumeration

---

Try this code instead:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Visible = True

With xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    .Cells.PasteSpecial XlPasteType.xlPasteValues
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, is there also a way i can exclude certain fields  and open a fixed excel sheet?

Comment: You could do this the other way around, by writing a macro in Excel that uses ADO to query your database, then use the `.CopyFromRecordset()` method but it's more advanced that this and impossible for me to give an example without being next to you at your computer! I'd suggest researching this though if you're working with DBs a lot - it will make your life a million times easier.